# Why do my TCP packets stop receiving ACK after a while?

Tags: tcp, network-programming

I'm writing an HTTP server on a very limited network device which uses uIP 1.0 as a TCP/IP stack. This library doesn't buffer any data, it only calls the user callback to provide a single packet to be sent or to re-issue previous data for retransmission. Next data packet is sent after the previous one has been ACKed by the remote side. First packet sent by my server is the response headers (45 bytes), then the file is sent in chunks of 846 bytes. The problem is that the remote side (macos or Linux, firefox or wget) stops sending ACKs starting with the third packet. Not getting any ACKs, my device starts retransmitting that packet and eventually resets the connection. This happens every time in exactly the same way. If I divide the data in smaller chunks (say, 256 bytes each), more packets get ACKed before ACKs stop coming - around 10 instead of 3.

Here is the dump of one session, the dump was performed on the client site (192.168.178.30) using wireshark:

```
      1 0.000000       192.168.178.30        192.168.178.70        TCP      78     56391 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=64 TSval=3618183324 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM
      2 1.001115       192.168.178.30        192.168.178.70        TCP      78     [TCP Retransmission] 56391 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=64 TSval=3618184325 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM
      3 1.096615       192.168.178.70        192.168.178.30        TCP      1008   80 → 56391 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=846 Len=0 MSS=846
      4 1.097032       192.168.178.30        192.168.178.70        TCP      54     56391 → 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0
      5 1.125337       192.168.178.30        192.168.178.70        TCP      192    56391 → 80 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=138
      6 1.447170       192.168.178.70        192.168.178.30        TCP      1008   80 → 56391 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=139 Win=846 Len=45
      7 1.447485       192.168.178.30        192.168.178.70        TCP      54     56391 → 80 [ACK] Seq=139 Ack=46 Win=65535 Len=0
      8 1.754454       192.168.178.70        192.168.178.30        TCP      1008   80 → 56391 [PSH, ACK] Seq=46 Ack=139 Win=846 Len=846
      9 1.754807       192.168.178.30        192.168.178.70        TCP      54     56391 → 80 [ACK] Seq=139 Ack=892 Win=65535 Len=0
     10 2.061660       192.168.178.70        192.168.178.30        TCP      1008   80 → 56391 [PSH, ACK] Seq=892 Ack=139 Win=846 Len=846
     11 2.794855       192.168.178.70        192.168.178.30        TCP      1008   [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 56391 [PSH, ACK] Seq=892 Ack=139 Win=846 Len=846
     12 3.597716       192.168.178.70        192.168.178.30        TCP      1008   [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 56391 [PSH, ACK] Seq=892 Ack=139 Win=846 Len=846
     13 4.645639       192.168.178.70        192.168.178.30        TCP      1008   [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 56391 [PSH, ACK] Seq=892 Ack=139 Win=846 Len=846
     14 6.567428       192.168.178.70        192.168.178.30        TCP      1008   [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 56391 [PSH, ACK] Seq=892 Ack=139 Win=846 Len=846
     15 9.844375       192.168.178.70        192.168.178.30        TCP      1008   [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 56391 [PSH, ACK] Seq=892 Ack=139 Win=846 Len=846
     16 15.988703      192.168.178.70        192.168.178.30        TCP      1008   [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 56391 [PSH, ACK] Seq=892 Ack=139 Win=846 Len=846
     17 22.132761      192.168.178.70        192.168.178.30        TCP      1008   [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 56391 [PSH, ACK] Seq=892 Ack=139 Win=846 Len=846
     18 28.277190      192.168.178.70        192.168.178.30        TCP      1008   [TCP Retransmission] 80 → 56391 [PSH, ACK] Seq=892 Ack=139 Win=846 Len=846
     19 34.318832      192.168.178.70        192.168.178.30        TCP      1008   80 → 56391 [RST, ACK] Seq=892 Ack=139 Win=846 Len=0
```

Comment: What is the application at the client end? And could you please provide the full packet capture as a pcap file, so that one can see what gets actually transmitted?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich at the client end I tried to use wget and firefox on macos and Linux. I've uploaded the full packet capture here: https://qdiv.dev/no-ack.pcapng

Comment: Thanks for added information. Unfortunately I cannot see anything which might cause this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packets which didn't receive the ACK had incorrect TCP checksum. Wireshark does not verify TCP checksum by default, that's why I didn't notice this problem.

Comment: Wireshark verifies TCP checksums:
https://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP_Checksum_Verification

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).